# What is the best api to work with google drive for iOS7?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, google-drive-api

What is the best API for google drive to work in iOS?, I had found this URL https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/quickstart for configuring google Derive API into our project it shows an error. Can anyone help me what is best API for google Drive and also proved me the tutorial to work with Google Drive.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Error shown in build in file library file like GTMGatherInputStream.h,GTMOAuth2Authentication.h,GTMHTTPFetchHistory.h.

Comment: google's tutorial is very easily to use..... it's the best api for google drive

Comment: When configuring that Google Drive API, There was error shown in the above mention file. How to use that in ios7?